# Program halts for a few minutes after video finishes playing on cv2 in Python

Tags: python, opencv, video

I'm reading video frames from an mp4 video file obtained from an IP camera. The code:

```
import cv2
from cv2 import VideoCapture

cap = VideoCapture(videoname)
frameNumber=0
while cap.isOpened():
    frameNumber+=1
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    print frameNumber
    if not ret:
        break
print 'done' # takes a few minutes
```

I understand that when the file finishes, there will be no more frames and  `ret` will become False. This should exit the loop.

However, when I run the file, the frames are printed and the last frame print then halts the program for a few minutes, and only then does 'done' appear.

I tried to search for solutions online but I can't seem to solve it even though it seems a straightforward problem. Appreciate any assistance.

EDIT: relevant information: Python ver 2.7.6, openCV ver 2.4.8, Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS.

Comment: Please, specify opencv and python versions, your platform (OS) and representative file (preferably small) to reproduce the issue

Comment: Thank you for the comment, the problem was the openCV version. updating to 3.0.0 solved this.